# Sharing configuration across multiple tracesources

Tags: c#, debugging, app-config, tracesource

I'm stuck with TraceSource configuration.

I have a lot of TraceSource following the "one per class pattern" and now I would like to configure all of them in a app.config.

Is it possible ?

I add that the TraceSource are in a .dll and I would like to use the .exe app.config.

Thanks for your help.

Vincent.

Comment: What do you mean by configure? Do you mean you want to set up the swtiches and listeners, i.e. filling in the <system.diagnostics> section? e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx